# How do I start server and pass commands simultaneously from Java?

Tags: java

I want to start a server and then pass commands to it. I want to start it from my `main()` and then pass the instructions. The issue is that when I start the server, then my program is waiting that I stop the server to take next instructions.
If possible, I would like to avoid to create a new class.
My code looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // run server
    Refine.main(args);


    //commands to pass
```

The Refine class comes from: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/blob/master/server/src/com/google/refine/Refine.java

Comment: Is it not possible to send the commands in the Refine class after you start the server?

Comment: It is surely possible but the I'd like to avoid. The aim would be to do something like 'Start server - pass commands - stop server'

Comment: Could you add the code where you are starting the server in the Refine class for better clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that `Refine` is your "server" main class and that calling `Refine.main` like that is equivalent to

```
$ java -cp ... Refine arg1 arg2 ...
```

In other words, your `Refine` class has a `public static void main(String[] args)` entrypoint method.

So how can you get this second `main` method start the server and then do something else while the server is running?

It depends on how `Refine.main` works.

- If it works by starting the server on another thread and then returning, then this may work:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Refine.main(args);
      // find handle for service
      // send commands.
  }
  ```
- If not, then you may need to do something like this:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      // start server in child thread
      new Thread(() -> Refine.main(args)).start();

      // find handle for service
      // send commands.
  }
  ```

But in either case, there are other problems to solve:

- You need to be able to obtain the handle (or URL, or whatever) for the server so that you can send it commands.
- You need a way to wait until the server is ready before sending it commands.

The solutions to those will depend on how the `Refine` class is implemented.

---

**UPDATE**

Ah ... so this the `com.google.refine.Refine` from OpenRefine.

The `Refine.main` method is synchronous.  If you look at the source code you will see that it is running the server on a private child thread and then waiting for that thread to terminate.  In other words, it behaves in the second way that I postulated above.

So to answer your question:

Q:  Is it possible to do what you are trying to do without writing your own class?

A:  No.  It is not possible.

Once you accept that you will *have to* write a new class, then there are two ways to do it:

1. In the way I suggested above.
2. You could actually write your own modifications for the `Refine` class.  Take a look at what it does.

Comment: As you're saying, it is working by starting the server on another thread, so I am using `Refine.main(args)` directly, and I can send commands if I start it, and then send the commands via another class. However, I'd like to avoid to do that, and do everything (start the server and then send the commands)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Then, I will probably create a new Class, as I actually import Refine as a jar, to import it into another module. If I modify the Refine class, I would have no flexibility at all I guess. Therefore I will just make all the classes of Refine as public